# Oracle Table constraint vs unique index?

Tags: oracle, database-design, constraints

1. What's difference constraint primary and unique key in Oracle ?
2. If I set a unique index for column A , and then Could I still set a
   constraint unique or primary key for column A or other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical difference between a primary key and a unique key is that all the columns in a primary key are mandatory, whereas we can have nulls in a unique key.

In terms of usage, a primary key should not change, whereas a unique can change.  In physical implementations this means that a table's primary key is often synthetic (generated with a sequence or similar mechanism) and its business key (say Customer Name) is enforced with a unique constraint.

Foreign key constraints should reference primary keys not unique keys.

A table can have only one primary key but any number of unique keys.  We can only have one index on any given permutation of columns.  So if we have a primary key on T23(COL_1) we cannot also build a unique key on T23(COL_1), and why would we want to?  However, we can build a  unique key on T23(COL_1, COL_2).

With regard to indexing, we can create a unique index on a table column and then use that index when adding a unique or primary key constraint.  (In fact we can use an ordinary index to enforce a primary key constraint, providing the actual values don't have any duplicates.)